# Problems with mongodb installation when deploying meteor application with mup on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-up

I am trying to deploy a meteor app on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation. After having tried several ways without success I am now trying to use meteor-up from https://github.com/sean-stanley/meteor-up/ , a version that has been created for this Ubuntu version, using systemd.

Unfortunately, I am not able to get it to work, there is a problem with the mongodb installation - I get the following error message when I run `mup setup`:

```
gpg: requesting key EA312927 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key EA312927: public key "MongoDB 3.2 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: 
sudo: stop: command not found
sudo: start: command not found
```

I have done some research to figure out how to fix this and I found that setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` might solve this issue. However it did not.

I tested it by typing `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` on the server shell and then rerun the `mup setup`command on my local machine, but with no luck, the error message remained.

Am I doing this variable setting wrong or is there another way of coming around this error above?